# How to group points based on mesh primitive membership

Tags: list-manipulation, regions, mesh, sorting, gathering

As a simple example of what I want to do, let's say I have a Voronoi mesh in a $10\times10$ area with $10$ random "seed points":

```
SeedRandom[1];
randMesh=VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{1, 10}, {10, 2}], {{1, 10}, {1, 10}}]
```

[image]

And I am interested in all integer points within this area. i.e. the $100$ points determined by

```
points = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 10}, {y, 10}], 1]
```

**What is an efficient way to group the points by the mesh section they reside in?**

One way I have thought of doing this is is just going point-by-point and checking each region, such as something like

```
{5, 5} \[Element] # & /@ MeshPrimitives[randMesh, 2]
```

> {False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False}

but applied to each point, and then grouping the points based on which mesh primitive they belong in.
But this is not very efficient, as in what I am actually doing I have a $512\times512$ area with about $1000$ seed points for the mesh. Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible already in version 12, but just undocumented.

```
grouped =  GatherBy[points, Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[randMesh]];
```

Apparently, this can find only top-dimensional cells. This is a good example where the syntax of undocumented code was changed in the final version.

Comment: Ugh I feel like I always get hit by the undocumented things. Thanks for the simple fix

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

In version 12.1 you can use [`NearestMeshCells`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestMeshCells.html) with [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) as follows:

```
grouped = GatherBy[points, NearestMeshCells[{randMesh, 2}, #] &];

Show[randMesh, 
 ListPlot[grouped, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  PlotLegends -> ("group-" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[Length @ grouped])]]
```

[image]

Comment: What if I have 12.0? :)

Comment: @AaronStevens it’s worth the upgrade! Especially for when undocumented functions go documented like in this example!

Comment: kglr, the link and linked term are missing a necessary s, I could not edit as it is less than 6 characters

Comment: Thank you @CATrevillian. I fixed it.

Comment: Is it possible to generate a more efficient version of the function `NearestMeshCells[{randMesh, 2}, #] &` with `NearestMeshCells[{randMesh, 2}]`? Typically, this is possible with `Nearest`-related constructs.

Comment: @Henrik, unlike `Nearest` the operator form (`NearestMeshCells[{randMesh, 2}]`) and multiple lists in the second argument (`NearestMeshCells[{randMesh, 2}, points]`) do not work.

Comment: What a shame! Thanks for checking.